# arc_ network interfaces in ChromeOS

Tags: linux, networking, android, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a Chromebook and if I open chrome://system/ in the Chromebrowser and expand the part ifconfig, then I see some trivial interfaces like eth0 or wlan0 and some mysterious interfaces like arc_eth0 or arc_wlan0 and some (virtual?) interfaces like vetharc0, vetheth0 or vethwlan0. While eth0 or wlan0 change the IP adresses depending on the DHCP server, the arc_ adresses are always the same all the time (like 100.115.92.5 for arc_eth0 or 100.115.92.13 for arc_wlan0).
If I installed via GooglePlay an Android app, the Android apps (like Termux) knows only the arc_ adresses. Servers see this arc_ adress too, if I connect an app with a server (like the SIP app Mizudroid -> on the telephone systeme server, I see this arc adress).

But what are these arc_ adresses? Virtual IP interfaces? An interlayer? And is it possible, to give the GooglePlay apps the possibility to use a "native" IP adress or the "native" interface?

Thank you very much!

Comment: the virtual address are for VMC (chrome's virtual machine manager) and the arc_ address are specifically for the Android VM

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar issue. Interestingly enough, mine are also in the 100.115.92.* range. My UI is telling me that I have an Ethernet IP of 10.10.10.184 and WiFi is disabled, while PortDroid app is showing eth0:100.115.92.6, arc0:100.115.92.2 and wlan0:100.115.92.14

If I do a subnet scan, I have dozens of unknown devices show up. I have only scratched the surface, but it looks like some kind of man in the middle attack.

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment. Please delete the answer and repost as a comment to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092193)